# How to handle big pictures in iPad application

Tags: objective-c, image, ipad

I have a couple of backgrounds that are the dimensions of the entire ipad screen (1024x768) and so I ask myself how to include them into my project. Should I stuff them onto sprite sheets or include them separately or load them from web ?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is less than 10MB, I would include them in the project as each file individually.

I would not use sprite sheets. Sprite sheets will not offer you much space advantage with the PNG encoding, and are not suited to an application where the image is changing infrequently (it will make your memory footprint bigger).

If your app is near or over the 10MB app store install over 3G limit, I would include the default background in the project and load the rest on demand using a framework such as SDWebImage.

Comment: I believe that for 3G and LTE networks, the download limit has been raised to 50MB.